# Do any 2020 Democratic primary candidates advocate for charter schools?

Tags: united-states, policy, primaries, education, privatization

I read this [Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/education/democrats-abandon-charter-schools-as-reform-agenda-falls-from-favor/2019/06/25/3cf4817e-904e-11e9-aadb-74e6b2b46f6a_story.html?utm_term=.966f0cbb8cc0) stating the 2020 Democratic presidential primary candidates are less in favor of charter schools than previous Democrats such as Barack Obama.

> If the candidates say anything about charter schools, it's negative. Education initiatives boosted by the Bush and Obama administrations are nowhere to be found in candidate platforms.
>
> Instead, the Democratic candidates are pitching billions of dollars in
>   new federal spending for schools and higher pay for teachers, with few
>   of the strings attached that marked the Obama-era approach to
>   education.

Do any 2020 Democratic primary candidates advocate for charter schools or consider them an important part of solving America's education problems?

Answer (score 1):

According to [US News](https://www.usnews.com/news/education-news/articles/2019-06-28/charter-school-advocates-punch-back-at-democratic-presidential-candidates), there are only two Democratic candidates who support charter schools. Elizabeth Warren and Joe Biden. On the Republican side, [Donald Trump](https://thinkprogress.org/trump-budget-charter-schools-f705cdf07603/) is also a staunch supporter of charter schools.

Comment: interestingly the article says "Other candidates who have been supportive of charter schools, like Sen. Elizabeth Warren of Massachusetts and former vice president Joe Biden, have downplayed that part of their resume – a move that speaks volumes in Biden's case since the number of students enrolled in charter schools more than doubled during the Obama administration." Which suggests they might be changing their stance or at least being more moderate in how they message it.

Comment: If they were to change their stance, that would not make any sense because they would lose a majority of their supporters.